# Alert in android

Tags: android

I am having a bitmap image. Can i show it in a Alert Dialog in android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a [custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can simply call the AlertDialog.Builder and set your image in there as setIcon(Drawable )
this way you will be able to put up you image on Dialog..

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Abhinava said, you can also create an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html), place your bitmap in there, and send the ImageView to the builder using [AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29).

The difference here being that your bitmap will be shown in the content area of the alert dialog instead of in the title.